# How to detect if Windows is directing traffic over LAN or over WiFi, if device is connected to Wifi + LAN in c#/c++

Tags: .net, windows, networking, console-application

The device is connected to Wifi + LAN,
need to find the primary network adapter or detect primary internet source via wifi or LAN

Comment: Why do you think Wi-Fi is not a LAN? If you want to distinguish a packet by interface, simply look at the address in the packet header. If you want the source, look at the source IP address in the packet header.

Comment: 1. If device is in proxy environment than which endpoint should be requested to check the ip address?
2. If device is connected to vpn, then that endpoint will use the vpn ip, that will also not able to identify vpn is accessible via wifi or lan?

Comment: If you are on a different network, all LAN (layer-2, e.g., ethernet Wi-Fi, etc.) information is stripped of when the frame is dropped from the packet. Absent NAT (only used for private<->public or overlapping addressing) the source and destination IP packet addresses are the original source and destination addresses. A proxy is a stand-in, and it is the endpoint, not the original endpoint. In any case, a host has no idea or need to know about a remote LAN. Routing loses all LAN information, leaving only network (IP) information.

Comment: But my usecase if device is connected both wifi + lan
Is there any .net or c++ api available which can tell from which device is accessing internet?

Comment: That is up to the routing table. Traffic to the Internet will use the default route. Look at the routing table to see which interface is used for the default route.

Comment: While connecting to lan+ wifi, in route table it showing default gateway for both wifi and lan
Using route print cmd to display

Comment: The route with the lowest metric is the active route. You should take the time to learn how networking works before you attempt to use it in programming, else you will have security holes.